# Iterating through python dictionary of proxies

Tags: python, python-requests

So I am using the requests module, but I am trying to change the proxy every time a request is made (Ex, GET and POST). I have a dictionary of all the proxies I want to use, but I am having trouble getting the request to actually work through iterating through the dictionary. I understand how to send a request with a single proxy, but again, I am not sure how to with changing each proxy after every request. This is not the current program I am trying to write, but similarly the task I am trying to accomplish:

```
BASE_URL = "Some url"
USER_AGENT = "Some user agent"
POST_URL = "Some url"

proxies = {
    'https' : 'proxy1',
    'https' : 'proxy2',
    'https' : 'proxy...'
}


def req():

        session = requests.Session()
        session.headers = {'user-agent': USER_AGENT}
        session.headers.update({'Referer': BASE_URL})
        req = session.get(BASE_URL, proxies=curProxy)

        session.headers.update({'x-csrftoken': req.cookies['csrftoken']})
        login_data = {'DATA HERE'}
        login = session.post(POST_URL, data=login_data, allow_redirects=True, proxies=curProxy)
        session.headers.update({'x-csrftoken': login.cookies['csrftoken']})
        cookies = login.cookies



# For each proxy in proxies
for proxy in proxies:
    # Updating the proxy to use
    curProxy = proxy
    req()
```

Thanks to all who reply in advance. All help/input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a dictionary for your proxies. Use a plain list:

```
proxies = ['proxy1', 'proxy2', ...]
```

Change your function `req` to accept the proxy as a parameter. Global variables are evil :)

```
def req(curProxy):
    ...
    req = session.get(BASE_URL, proxies={'http': curProxy, 'https': curProxy})
```

Then iterate

```
for proxy in proxies:
    req(proxy)
```

Comment: The request module says it should be formated a certain way. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies Not sure if it can be accepted a different way though

Comment: Sorry, I remembered the `proxies=` usage wrongly. I adapted my answer, it should work now. I'm assuming you want the same proxy for http and https.